# Why is Twitter API returning > rpp value?

Tags: twitter

I have a simple script to pull 100 results per page. It is actually returning more than 100. Am I missing something?

Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
<?php 
    $request = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=obama&rpp=100&result_type=mixed';
    $handle = fopen($request, "r");
    $twt = stream_get_contents($handle);
    fclose($handle);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>tweets</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='tweets'></div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tweets = <?php echo json_encode($twt); ?>;
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(tweets);
    function getTweets() {
        for (var i = obj.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            $('#tweets').append((i+1) + '<br />' + obj.results[i].text+'<br /><br />');
        };
    }
    getTweets();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I can repeat this bug using the twitter gem v2.2.0 when executing `Twitter.search([query], rpp: 100)` and when making an HTTP request to `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=obama&rpp=100` or for any other search value.

Comment: My reproduction of the bug always resulted in the number of results returned being short of the requested number of results.

Comment: I have had fewer results than 100 as well as greater than 100. The low was 98 and the high was 104 results. I am hoping it has something to do with the return from twitter and not the code, as I can use a similar query to get results from the topsy otter API and get 100 results exactly. Not totally relevant, but thought I would add that.